# Use rails controllers in C#

Tags: c#, ruby-on-rails, http, get, crud

I have a Rails app where I can do all the CRUD in a web page, but I need to make a console application in C# to access the controllers of the rails app and use it.

Anyone can help me, here is my code for the rails app.

```
 class UsuariosController < ApplicationController
  # GET /usuarios
  # GET /usuarios.json
  def index
    @usuarios = Usuario.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @usuarios }
    end
  end

  # GET /usuarios/1
  # GET /usuarios/1.json
  def show
    @usuario = Usuario.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @usuario }
    end
  end

  # GET /usuarios/new
  # GET /usuarios/new.json
  def new
    @usuario = Usuario.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @usuario }
    end
  end

  # GET /usuarios/1/edit
  def edit
    @usuario = Usuario.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /usuarios
  # POST /usuarios.json
  def create
    @usuario = Usuario.new(params[:usuario])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @usuario.save
        format.html { redirect_to @usuario, notice: 'El usuario fue creado con exito.' }
        format.json { render json: @usuario, status: :created, location: @usuario }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @usuario.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /usuarios/1
  # PUT /usuarios/1.json
  def update
    @usuario = Usuario.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @usuario.update_attributes(params[:usuario])
        format.html { redirect_to @usuario, notice: 'El usuario fue actualizado con exito.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @usuario.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /usuarios/1
  # DELETE /usuarios/1.json
  def destroy
    @usuario = Usuario.find(params[:id])
    @usuario.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to usuarios_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: "*console application in C# to access the controllers of the rails app and use it*" do you mean you want to be able to make HTTP requests to your rails app? If so, see [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: no chance to use rails controllers in a c# application.. rails and .net mvc are 2 different frameworks.. if you want to access a rails app controller from c# app you have to make a get/post request to the controller/action..

Comment: Yes @MaximilianoPoggio I want to make a get/post request to the controller but I do not know how, can you give me some advice or orientation to where to start please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make a GET request to a rails controller like UsuariosController you can do :

```
public static string HttpGet(string URI) 
{
   System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URI);
   req.Proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy(ProxyString, true);
   System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
   System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
   return sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
}
```

For example, if you want to access www.yourpage.com/Usuarios and get the users, that's the uri you have to call. (This will call index action, that is the default routing actionin your controllers i suppose). Or if you want to use another action..  /Usuarios/id/SomeMethodReturningSomething

Answer (score 1):

[IronRuby](http://ironruby.codeplex.com/)* might help!

**"an open source implementation of the Ruby programming language for .NET and Silverlight, heavily relying on Microsoft's Dynamic Language Runtime"*